# Laravel session and auth issue in MacOS

Tags: macos, laravel, session, authentication, mamp

I have a issue with my laravel project in macOS. I have project where in a moment could be have two auth actives, with diferent guard. Is a place where teacher can be accés to play like a student. Then I use two guards and some sessions variables. After do the second auth in ajax Request, the code have a redirect. In mac this redirect goes to login page and not to Student home.
This source works perfect in windows, and in Linux Server. But not in MAMP or XAMPP in macOs.
Some idea?

thank you